# Why is the number of non zero rows in row echelon form of the matrix the rank of the matrix

Tags: matrices, matrix-rank

I have no idea about how to prove this statement hence require a proof. The only definition I have is that rank is the highest order square submatrix of a matrix which has non-zero determinant.Our professor has given the statement in question as a definition without any prrof hence asking for help.Thanks!

Comment: Is the rank preserved at each step of Gaussian elimination?

Answer (score 0):

The rank of a matrix also tells you how many linearly independent vectors it has i.e. if rank is 2 then there will be 2 linearly independent vectors in the matrix. And these vectors will be the columns (given your vectors are the columns of the matrix) that contain leading 1's in the rref of said matrix. And if you observe, you will see that the number of leading 1's will always be equal to the number of non-zero rows in the rref of a matrix. Thus rank = # of non-zero rows in the rref of a matrix.